# Brackets To each Line of Data in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach

My problem is that i have a foreach loop that saves every row of data into a List and then creates a TXT from the list, the problem is that my data is saved into the TXT in this form:

```
 ["ROW1","DATA1","DATA2","DATA3","ROW2","DATA4","DATA5","DATA6"]
```

And i want to make my txt to have the data like this:

```
[["ROW1","DATA1","DATA2","DATA3"],["ROW2","DATA4","DATA5","DATA6"]]
```

Getting each row into a separate aditional brackets brackets("[]"), how can i do this without using another List?

This is my Foreach Loop:

```
  List<string> listaprocedure = new List<string>();
  foreach (DataRow dato in myTable.Rows)
  {
       foreach (DataColumn datoC in myTable.Columns)
       {
             listaprocedure.Add(dato[datoC].ToString());
       }
  }

  json4 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(procedimiento2);
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\procedure.txt", json4);
```

Comment: "without using another List" - why? List of lists would be so much easier to serialize with default JSON serializer that coming up with some strange custom code to split array during serialization...

Comment: when i use list of list i get an Systemutofmmemory exeption since my data is way to big and i itarate it 3 times to make it unles i am doing it wrong @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: That's strange - building one huge list is more expensive than building list of lists (same overall number of items split over multiple smaller blocks with less need to copy huge blocks of memory...)

Comment: then i think im building wrong my list of list, how could i get a list of list of this foreach loop @Alexei??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually iterate through rows, writing each one as you have read it, then add `,` after it (except last row). Plus add `[` and `]` at the beginning and end.

Quite ugly, but can help if you deal with really big table.
But the best option is to populate `List<List<string>>` (or `string[,]`).

Anyway here is working example:

```
using (var reader = File.CreateText("C:\\procedure.txt"))
{
    // Starting outer json array
    reader.WriteLine("[");

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myTable.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        var row = myTable.Rows[rowIndex];
        var rowValues = new List<string>(); // can be reused if needed
        foreach (DataColumn column in myTable.Columns)
            rowValues.Add(row[column].ToString());

        var jsonRow = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rowValues);

        // Write current row
        reader.Write(jsonRow);

        // Add separating comma
        if (rowIndex != myTable.Rows.Count - 1)
            reader.WriteLine(",");
    }

    // End outer json array
    reader.WriteLine("]");
}
```

Comment: im trying to test this answer but i get and error on the "File.CreateText("C:\\procedure.txt"))" says "is a method wich it not valid in the given context"

Comment: Which .Net Framework you have? When (compilation or runtime) do you get this message?

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, this works:

```
var query =
    from dr in myTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    from dc in myTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
    group dr[dc].ToString() by dc.Ordinal / 4;

var json4 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
```

This gives me:

```
[["ROW1","DATA1","DATA2","DATA3"],["ROW2","DATA4","DATA5","DATA6"]]
```

I used this code to initialize my data:

```
var myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("A1", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("A2", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("A3", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("A4", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("B1", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("B2", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("B3", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("B4", typeof(string));
myTable.Rows.Add("ROW1", "DATA1", "DATA2", "DATA3", "ROW2", "DATA4", "DATA5", "DATA6");
```